# Side Scrolling a PDF in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Is there a way to get a PDF that has been loaded into a UIWebView to scroll horizontally instead of vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can't do this with UIWebView but instead have to use Quartz. Hope this is helpful to anyone searching for the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could file a feature request with Apple at http://bugreporter.apple.com